# Am I allowed to post links to ebooks in my profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, copyright

Am I allowed to post links to ebooks in my profile?

I am not sure if I can and do not want to get banned or something, because I am evil, just look at my username!

Comment: As long as you're not violating copyright, I don't see why not. However, this site should not be used for advertisement.

Comment: I remember at least one user who has in their profile as the website some site similar to [library.nu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library.nu). (I do not want to name users and I do not want to mention some sites either, but library.nu might be a good example, since it is not working anymore.) Would some site like this, providing link to *illegal downloads* still be ok in a profile, @robjohn? (I am not really sure what term I should use, but *illegal downloads* is close enough and most people here would understand what I mean.) I assume that the OP is asking about this kind of site.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I would be uncomfortable with someone doing what you say. (I know that I am not a moderator, but I thought I should say anyway...)

Comment: Somewhat relevant: SE on what is expected of Moderators http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114919/what-should-i-do-when-i-see-copyright-violations-posted-on-stack-overflow (The short of it is: not too much. But we are free to be more strict.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: the question asks about posting links to eBooks. If those eBooks are legally available for free (i.e. no copyright violation), that seems fine. Posting links to sites illegally distributing eBooks is a different matter. I would discourage such postings. However, it is hard to police such things.